# Office JS how to track text typing

Tags: office-js

I have question about Office Apps (Office JS).
I need to track if user was finished typing and hit return('Enter') key, but I can't find any examples in google or microsoft... so can anyone help me with this question or give link to examples about Office-js>

P.S now I'm trying to do it in Word, but in future it would be in all MS Office applications(Word, Excel, PP, Outlook)

Comment: it will be really useful if you can add more details to your question, like for example, is this for Excel, Word, PPT, Outlook? there is no key pressed event in office application but depending on your scenario you can enable certain alternatives.

Comment: @Juan Balmori  see my edits